# how to use if condition in jQuery foreach loop

Tags: jquery, json

i have a json string with some detail and i want to get value from json string according to if condition but there is something wrong that i am not getting value.
what is i want do there is two car type **4Seater** and **8Seater** in dropdown when i change car type then i want to all cars name from json string in option on the next dropdown that is cars. i have tried below code but is not showing any option. i have no idea what to do.

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<body>
    <select id="capacity">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="4Seater">4Seater</option>
        <option value="8Seater">8Seater</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cars"></select>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var jsonstirn = '[{"capacity":"4Seater","carname":"car1","price":"83"},{"capacity":"4Seater","car2":"i10","price":"83"},{"capacity":"8Seater","carname":"car3","price":"83"}]';
            var jsonarray = JSON.parse(jsonstirn);

            $('#capacity').change(function(){
                var cars = ''
                var capacityval = $('#capacity').val();
                $.each(jsonarray,function(i,item){
                    if(item.capacity == capacityval){
                        cars+='<option value="'+item.carname+'">'+item.carname+'</option>';
                    };
                });
                $('#cars').html(cars);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I think there is an "a" missing in `item.capcity ==` Does that help?

Comment: after correct the mistake it is not working it is showing on only first value like when i select 4Seater in the next dropdown there is showing firsti option **car1** and second is showing **undefined**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is spelling mistake of item.capacity, You have used item.capcity instead of capacity, use this:

```
 $.each(jsonarray,function(i,item){
    if(item.capacity == capacityval){
         cars+='<option value="'+item.carname+'">'+item.carname+'</option>';
    };
});


// set json :

 var jsonstirn = '[{"capacity":"4Seater","carname":"car1","price":"83"},{"capacity":"4Seater","carname":"i10","price":"83"},{"capacity":"8Seater","carname":"car3","price":"83"}]';
```

Comment: after correct the mistake it is not working it is showing on only first value like when i select 4Seater in the next dropdown there is showing firsti option **car1** and second is showing **undefined**

Comment: because your json is incorrect. set    var jsonstirn = '[{"capacity":"4Seater","carname":"car1","price":"83"},{"capacity":"4Seater","carname":"i10","price":"83"},{"capacity":"8Seater","carname":"car3","price":"83"}]';

Comment: see here in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/630n77aa/

Comment: in second index: you have written "car2":"i10" but it should be  "carname":"i10"

Comment: @VijayKumar Format your JSON code and look at it.

Comment: ohh i got  the issue thanks @DharaParmar